# Name for an item that is out of tolerance or over a threshold

Tags: single-word-requests, software

I'm looking for a word to name an item that is outside a set tolerance. For example, I have to place a signpost within 3 feet of a building but I put it 4 feet away. That signpost is outside the tolerance, it goes over the allowed threshold, it is a(n)...

I was thinking it's "an outlier" or "a deviant" but those don't seem to quite meet the case, and a thesaurus search didn't turn up anything else.

It's for a term in a software dialog, so I'm looking for something short and sweet. Like "Process Deviants (Y/N)" - but not deviant because a) it sounds stupid, and b) it doesn't imply over a tolerance limit (which is important here).

Any suggestions? I'm hoping that there is such a word and that someone knows it!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the naming of software artifacts is specifically off-topic for this site.

Comment: aberration
    deviation
    eccentricity
    exception
    oddity
    anomaly
    deviance
    irregularity
    quirk
    bohemian
    dissenter
    dissident
    eccentric
    heretic
    iconoclast
    maverick
    nonconformist
    original
    outsider

Comment: Why do none of the easily identified synonyms suit you???

Comment: Why not say *out of range*?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're seeking a noun, but if you're willing to nominalize a verb, you could choose to use the word **breach**.

Per *OED* definition **1.b.** of **breach** as a verb:

> *figurative; spec.* in Financial and Stock Exchange jargon, to go beyond (above or below) (a figure)

A citation in the *OED* from *The Economist* presents a good example of its use to mean "breaking over a tolerance or threshold

> **1984**   Economist 10 Mar. 52/2   So far, Mr Nakasone has not dared to **breach** the 1% mark.

**Breach** is also a noun.  The *OED* does not explicitly denote a noun meaning for "breach" that means "an instance of breaking over a tolerance or threshold," but since the term is used this way as a verb frequently in technical fields, the meaning would be clear if you were to write something along the line of "Process breaches."

It is worth noting that as a noun, the word tends to mean a kind of "breaking."  Hence, "data breaches" is a common term in the information security community.  In the case of this example it would be taken to indicate that the item has "broken" out of the tolerance level.

Comment: Breach? Yes, that could work. I'll perhaps ponder a bit more, but this is the best so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**noncomplier** works for this.

> Significant noncomplier (SNC) means a water system that is violating or has violated department rules and the violations may create or have created an imminent or a significant risk to human health.

https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/significant-noncomplier-snc

> A habitual noncomplier (HNC, also known as an egregious repeater) is an individual with a history or
>   pattern of noncompliance—a person who serially and deliberately does not comply—even 
>   after compliance intervention.

https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-soi/12resconnoncomply.pdf

Comment: What if it will compile, but function checks when you try to run it?

Comment: @HotLicks This tempts me to actually post my opossums/apothegms comment under one of Sven's recent answers.

Answer (score 0):

I know it means something different to you, since you're a software developer (like me), but this sounds like an *exception*:

> a case to which a rule does not apply

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exception))

A reasonable alternative would be to adjectivize it, e.g. "Process exceptional cases".

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to physically manufactured things that don't meet the intended specifications for them, a good word might be **defect** (or **defective**).

Some relevant definitions [from the OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/48757):

> 2. a. An imperfection in a person or thing; a shortcoming, a failing; a fault, flaw, or abnormality.
> 3. The quality, state, or fact of being imperfect; defectiveness, faultiness.

If the problem is one of the use of an object, rather than its inherent characteristics, another term related to one you've been considering might be more appropriate. A **deviation** is a difference from a desired state. Here are [the relevant OED definitions](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/51460):

> 1. a. The action of deviating; turning aside from a path or track; swerving, deflection.
> 2. a. Divergence from the straight line, from the mean, or standard position; variation, deflection; the amount of this
> 3. figurative. a. Divergence from any course, method, rule, standard, etc.; with *a* and *plural*, an instance of this.

Another idea is to pick a word related to the rules that are being broken. If its a law or regulation you're not obeying when you put the sign four feet from the building instead of three, you might call it a **violation**. If it's a contract you're not fulfilling the terms of, you might call it a **breach** (of the contract).

Or you might pick a term related to the specific topic you're dealing with. If your software is dealing specifically with sign placement issues, you might want to use **invalid placement** rather than using a more general term that might be less clear in your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

***Transgressor*** might work.

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/transgress) gives the verb definition

> Transgress
>   verb (used with object) to pass over or go beyond (a limit, boundary,
>   etc.): to transgress bounds of prudence.

Answer (score 0):

#### infringement

From the second meaning of *infringement* ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/infringement)):

> *(variable noun)* An infringement of a law or rule is the act of breaking it or disobeying it.

So

> Process Infringements? (Y/N)

or perhaps qualified

> Process Threshold Infringements? (Y/N)

or

> Process Tolerance Infringements? (Y/N)

#### violation

A near-synonym of *infringement* but perhaps harsher and in greater need of qualification, e.g. *threshold violation* or *tolerance violation*. From the first meaning of *violation* ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/violation)):

> *(noun)* infringement or breach, as of a law, rule, right, etc.

So

> Process Threshold Violations? (Y/N)

or

> Process Tolerance Violations? (Y/N)